# Unwanted ScrollViewer inside ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollviewer

I have following XAML,

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ChannelInfoTemplate">
    <WrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Background="AliceBlue" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

And,

```
<DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FilesList}" Name="FilesItemControl" Background="Transparent" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Channels">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding Channels,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                            Name="ChannelsView" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ChannelsTemplate}" 
                                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                            Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" 
                                                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                                            Tag="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

In my application I observed that whenever I select a first file with no of channels ListView's width is set according to the channel numbers. That means width is set according to content inside the ListView. But when I close the first file and open 2nd one then ListView's width is doesn't change. So if the new file is with more no of channels than first one then it shows scollviewer which I don't want. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Close and open? Please always provide a repo of your issue when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mm8 Different files have different data.(Number of channels), which I am showing in ListView. ListView's width is getting set according to first file's no of channels. Suppose there are 4 channels then width will be 120. But now I need to show 2nd file's data in ListView which has 6 channels. But width of ListView remains 120 and ScollViewer appears.

Comment: So where is the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your issue?